# Capture any errors from my select statement that has multiple NOT EXISTS within it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

My CATCH is not inserting the error into my DB_Error table.  The catch works fine with a simple select from table but not capturing the error from this code.

I wasn't able to find anything on the net about this

```
BEGIN TRY
insert into Table1 (MachineID, JobNumber, PartNum, MACHOP, Descriptions, PPHour)
select  DISTINCT    
        Table2.MachineID, 
        Table2.JobNumber,
        Table2.PartNum,
        Table2.MACHOP,
        Table2.Descriptions,
        Table2.PPHour
from    Table2
where 
NOT EXISTS (Select * from Table1
            where   Table2.MachineID = Table1.MachineID
            and Table2.JobNumber = Table1.JobNumber)
and
not exists (select * from Table3 
            where   Table2.MachineID] = Table3.MachineID
            and Table2.JobNumber] = Table3.JobNumber)

and
not exists (select * from Table4 
            where   Table2.MachineID = Table4.MachineID
            and Table2.JobNumber = Table4.JobNumber)

and
not exists (select * from Table5 
            where   Table2.MachineID = Table5.MachineID
            and Table2.JobNumber= Table5.JobNumber)

and
not exists (select * from Table6
            where   Table2.MachineID = Table6.MachineID
            and Table2.JobNumber = Table6.JobNumber)
and
not exists (select * from Table7 
            where   Table2.MachineID = Table7.MachineID]
            and     Table2.JobNumber = Table7.JobNumber)

and
not exists (select * from Table8 
            where   Table2.MachineID = Table8.MachineID
            and Table2.JobNumber = Table8.JobNumber)

END TRY


BEGIN CATCH  
    INSERT INTO db_errors
    VALUES  
        (SUSER_SNAME(),
      ERROR_NUMBER()   
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() 
        ,ERROR_STATE()  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() 
        ,ERROR_LINE() 
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() 
     ,GETDATE());
 END CATCH
```

So the error I received is

> (0 row(s) affected) Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 246 Invalid
>   object name
>   'BoleyToolAccessDB.dbo.MachOPNotInPartsRunTimeTableFromRincoMTMDB'.

The table is missing.  I want the CATCH to insert the error into the DB_Error table.

Comment: 'BoleyToolAccessDB.dbo.MachOPNotInPartsRunTimeTableFromRincoMTMDB'.

Is Table6

Comment: Question is mistagged this does not like valid MySQL code and or a MySQL related error message, this seams to be SQL Server (MSSQL) related.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Express (64-bit)  Version 12.0.4522.0

Comment: You have a compilation error which cannot be caught - try/catch will only catch runtime errors. Your script never executes because it does not compile. Erland discusses [error handling](http://www.sommarskog.se/index.html0 in tsql along with other (some related perhaps) topics.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you SMor, I was able to capture the error by modifying my code to reflect this example. 
These errors are not entirely uncatchable; you cannot catch them in the scope they occur, but you can catch them in outer scopes. 
CREATE PROCEDURE outer_sp AS
   BEGIN TRY
      EXEC inner_sp
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
      PRINT 'The error message is: ' + error_message()
   END CATCH
go
EXEC outer_sp
Now we get this output:
This prints
The error message is: Invalid object name 'NoSuchTable'.
This time the error is caught because there is an outer CATCH handler.